# How to write script to run another script when content in file is modified

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I would like to write a script to run another script. When receiving a file from another machine; for example, if content in that file is "a" run example.sh And that file is needed to be watched all the time. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Have you done any research on cron jobs?

Comment: Yes. I used to use cron jobs to schedule task. Do you have guild for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with `inotify`:

```
inotifywait -e moved_to -m receiving_dir/ | 
while read path action file; do 
  [[ $action = MOVED_TO && $(grep "a" $path$file) ]] && /home/user/./exampĺe.sh;
done
```

Comment: The `entr` program is also good for this kind of approach.